# Customize package and deployment

Tags: vb6, installation, setup-deployment

I want to run my vb6 application at windows startup.

I am able to do it manually but want to automate it during installation.

Please suggest me how to customize the setup and deployment program to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which setup and deployment program are you using? PDW requires adding code to their example setup. Inno (and others) support it easily.

Comment: @deanna,i am using PDW.Please also let me know if it is possible to add custom action while uninstalling the application (like cleaning up the files created during application usage etc.).

Comment: I stopped using the PDW many years ago. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how specifically to do this in your install package, but you should just need to write an entry into one of the [automatic startup locations](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-program-automatic-startup-locations/) in the registry. The **RunOnce** keys are deleted, then run once, just like you would guess. The others are run each time the user logs in to Windows.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
```